# Stata: Can I use "by" for a block of code?

Tags: block, stata

I know and love `by`. But I wonder if it is somehow possible to "by" an entire block of code instead of just a single command.
This would be useful if one would first like to use a command that stores values (e.g. count) and then do something with those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the sense that you can write a program and make it `byable` and Stata programmers do this routinely.

http://www.stata.com/manuals14/pbyable.pdf

No, in the sense that `by:` is a prefix to a single command (so, as above, whatever you specify must be specified by one line).

Comment: Is there any way to do something comparable then? I know I can create a group variable and then loop over it, but within the loop, I can never act "as if I operated on the entire dataset" -- which would make things a lot easier in many cases

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you are making or the difficulty you are perceiving.  You can write a do-file and call it in a loop over the distinct levels of your classifying variable. Please give concrete examples of what you want to do and ask questions based on specific code.